# Dummy variables in multiple regression

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, categorical-data, effect-size

Let's suppose I measure weights of eight male and eight female mice, from four litters, that were subjected to two different treatments: a and b

Here are my data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(sex = c(rep("m",8),rep("f",8)), treatment = rep(c(rep("a",4),rep("b",4)),2))
df$weight <- c(rnorm(4,1),rnorm(4,2),rnorm(4,3),rnorm(4,4))
    df$litter <- rep(c(rep("l1",2),rep("l2",2),rep("l3",2),rep("l4",2)),2)
```

Now I fit a mixed effects model to the interaction between sex and treatment, which are categorical fixed effects, and litter is defined as a random effect:

```
df$sex = as.factor(df$sex)
df$treatment = as.factor(df$treatment)
df$litter = as.factor(df$litter)


fit <- lmer(weight ~ sex*treatment + (1|litter), data = df)
```

And here's the output:

```
summary(fit)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: weight ~ sex * treatment + (1 | litter)
   Data: df

REML criterion at convergence: 38.6

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.47793 -0.54377 -0.01737  0.48467  1.45905 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 litter   (Intercept) 0.4318   0.6571  
 Residual             0.7574   0.8703  
Number of obs: 16, groups:  litter, 4

Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)      3.54300    0.63662   5.565
sexm            -2.46379    0.61541  -4.004
treatmentb       0.01801    0.90031   0.020
sexm:treatmentb  1.08648    0.87032   1.248

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) sexm   trtmnt
sexm        -0.483              
treatmentb  -0.707  0.342       
sxm:trtmntb  0.342 -0.707 -0.483
```

Obviously the "f" sex and the "a" treatment are set as dummy variables to a zero baseline.
My question relates to the interpretation: is there a way to extract the effect size of the dummy variables? 
Alternatively, if I add an additional sex and treatment variable, for which I set weight to 0, will they therefore serve as dummy variables that really have a zero effect size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `R` package `{lmerTest}` and call on the following function:

```
summary(fit)
Linear mixed model fit by REML t-tests use Satterthwaite approximations to
  degrees of freedom [lmerMod]
Formula: weight ~ sex * treatment + (1 | litter)
   Data: df

REML criterion at convergence: 38.6

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.47793 -0.54377 -0.01737  0.48467  1.45905 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 litter   (Intercept) 0.4318   0.6571  
 Residual             0.7574   0.8703  
Number of obs: 16, groups:  litter, 4

Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)      3.54300    0.63662  3.34300   5.565  0.00853 **
sexm            -2.46379    0.61541 10.00000  -4.004  0.00250 **
treatmentb       0.01801    0.90031  3.34300   0.020  0.98518   
sexm:treatmentb  1.08648    0.87032 10.00000   1.248  0.24033   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) sexm   trtmnt
sexm        -0.483              
treatmentb  -0.707  0.342       
sxm:trtmntb  0.342 -0.707 -0.483
```

Under *random effects*, the `litter` ***Std. Dev.*** of `0.6571` measures the variability between litters, as opposed to the variability that is still unaccounted for (`0.8703`). This can be visually inspected with boxplots:

[image]

Among the *fixed effects* the differences will simply be in intercepts, also illustrated with boxplots:

[image]

Notice on the output that the actual ***intercepts*** should be calculated as:

```
fixef(fit)
    (Intercept)            sexm      treatmentb sexm:treatmentb 
     3.54300434     -2.46379392      0.01800987      1.08647799
```

so that the `(Intercept)` in the output (i.e. $\small3.543$) is the average of *females* treated with `a`:

```
> a_fem <- df[df$sex=="f" & df$treatment=="a",]; mean(a_fem$weight) [1] 3.543004
```

The *second coefficient* is the average for *males* treated with `a` ($\small 3.543 - 2.464 = 1.079$):

```
> a_male <- df[df$sex=="m" & df$treatment=="a",]; mean(a_male$weight) [1] 1.07921
```

The *third coefficient* is for *females* treated with `b`, amounting to ($\small 3.543 + 0.018 = 3.561$):

```
> b_fem <- df[df$sex=="f" & df$treatment=="b",]; mean(b_fem$weight) [1] 3.561014
```

Finally the *last coefficient* stands for *males* treated with `b` or ($\small 3.543−2.464+0.018+1.083=2.187$):

```
> b_male <- df[df$sex=="m" & df$treatment=="b",]; mean(b_male$weight) [1] 2.183698
```

We see in the output that there is a significant difference in intercepts in `females treated with a` *and* `males treated with a`.

The fixed effects coefficients come with the ***standard errors*** calculated. Otherwise, they can be extracted from the variance-covariance matrix:

```
vcov(fit)
4 x 4 Matrix of class "dpoMatrix"
                (Intercept)       sexm treatmentb sexm:treatmentb
(Intercept)       0.4052795 -0.1893622 -0.4052795       0.1893622
sexm             -0.1893622  0.3787245  0.1893622      -0.3787245
treatmentb       -0.4052795  0.1893622  0.8105590      -0.3787245
sexm:treatmentb   0.1893622 -0.3787245 -0.3787245       0.7574489
```

For example, for `females treated with b`:

`(fem_b_SE <- sqrt(diag(vcov(fit)))[3]) [1] 0.9003105`

The ***confidence intervals*** can be calculated as follows for example in the case of `female treated with b`:

```
(fem_b_SE <- sqrt(diag(vcov(fit)))[3]) [1] 0.9003105    
(fem_b_coef <- fixef(fit)[1] + fixef(fit)[3]) 
3.561014 
(fem_b_CI <- fem_b_coef + c(-1, 1) * qnorm(0.975) * fem_b_SE)
[1] 1.796438   5.325590
```

or in the case of `males treated with b`:

```
(male_b_SE <- sqrt(diag(vcov(fit)))[4]) [1] 0.8703154
(male_b_coef <- sum(fixef(fit)[1:4]))
2.183698
(male_b_CI <- male_b_coef + c(-1, 1) * qnorm(0.975) * male_b_SE)
[1] 0.4779114   3.8894852
```

Notice that the function built into `lme4` gives different values:

```
confint(fit)
Computing profile confidence intervals ...
                     2.5 %    97.5 %
.sig01           0.0000000  1.308364
.sigma           0.5581087  1.251771
(Intercept)      2.4416191  4.644389
sexm            -3.6591640 -1.268425
treatmentb      -1.5518958  1.589257
sexm:treatmentb -0.6040305  2.776985
```

are significantly different, and give a bunch of error messages.

Comment: Antoni,in your last step where you derive the mean value for `sexm:treatmentb`, you are missing the estimate for `treatmentb`,so instead of $\small 3.543−2.46+1.086=2.165$, it should be $\small 3.543−2.464+0.018+1.083=2.187$, which also matches your calculated mean value. If that is correct than the example confidence interval should also reflect this.Also if you ran `lsmeans::lsmeans(fit, pairwise~sex:treatment)`, you will get the same mean values you calculated and lower and upper CLs.However they are different from yours and also different from `confint(fit)`.Not sure which way to go here?!

Comment: @Stefan Thank you very much. I didn't realize the calculated values were different, which had tipped me off to the coefficient I had forgotten to include. It's now fixed. I'm looking into your other comments. It's great you paid attention to potentially misleading info!

Comment: No problem Antoni :) If you found out more about which confidence limits to use, please let me know. Thanks!